# Does the Kuo-toa's Sticky Shield reaction work on natural weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, reactions

As the title says, the Kuo-toa creature has a reaction that can catch weapons. I'm curious if it works on natural weapons like bites and punches. Here is the text in question.

> **Sticky Shield**. When a creature misses the kuo-toa with a melee weapon attack, the kuo-toa uses its sticky shield to catch the weapon. The attacker must succeed on a DC 11 Strength saving throw, or the weapon becomes stuck to the kuo-toa's shield. If the weapon's wielder can't or won't let go of the weapon, the wielder is grappled while the weapon is stuck. While stuck, the weapon can't be used. A creature can pull the weapon free by taking an action to make a DC 11 Strength check and succeeding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Natural weapons are weapons.

This is clarified in the *Sage Advice Compendium*:

> **Are natural weapons considered weapons?**
> Things designated as weapons by the rules, including natural weapons, are indeed weapons. In contrast, unarmed strikes are not weapons. They are something you do with an unarmed part of your body.

So yes, Sticky Shield does work here, since it says:

> When a creature misses the kuo-toa with a *melee weapon attack*, the kuo-toa uses its sticky shield to catch *the weapon*.

A creature using a natural weapon would likely fall under the category of "can't let go of the weapon".

Note, this feature does nothing for Unarmed Strikes, which do not count as weapons, per the SAC question quoted above.